# Angular template scope access after angular.element(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, symfony, twig

I'm very new to Angular.
Trying the Symfony2 + AngularJS combination now, and i'm having the following problem:

Inside my  inside index.html i have this:

```
<script>
   global = {};
     $(document).ready(function() {
     global.test = {{ test|json_encode|raw }} //From Twig to JS;
});
</script
```

In my controller i have the following:

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.test = global.test; // From JS global to Controller Scope
});
```

Now when i have the following in my template it does not show anything:

```
<!-- I have {[{ '' }]} instead of {{ '' }} for use of AngularJS to prevent conflict -->
<div>
     <h1>{[{test}]}</h1> //Prints nothing..
</div>
```

I presume this is because (ofcourse) the DOM and Angular are being rendered concurrently, after which the (document).ready() function executes.
I would like to have the content that is being assigned in the (document).ready() to be available in the view/model.

How can i do this??

Thanks!

Comment: why are you using `$(ducument).ready()` for variable that has nothing to do with DOM? same with `angular.element(document).ready()`  . WHere did that idea come from? Is not something you use in angular

Comment: Ok suppose i remove those, how would i make this work? The first $(document).ready() is useless now that you point it out. But how will i assign the twig to a controller scope variable then?

Comment: I got it! After what you said i realised the document ready was the actual problem. THANKS, sometimes a little push in the back is really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to charlietfl's comment i realised the (document).ready() functions were the problem i created myself. I just overcomplicated the whole thing with a very illogical approach.

In the HTML :

```
<script>
  var global = {};
      global.test = {{ test|json_encode|raw }};
</script>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.test = global.test;
```

HTML file Angular binding:

```
 {[{ test }]}
```